# Receiving accessDenied when using App Only permissions calling Graph API sites?search=*

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sites

I have a web application which uses App only tokens to override the end user's permission to retrieve all Site Collections in the tenant. When attempting to use the boiler plate code provided in [the example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#http-request) with one minor change, the Graph API is returning `accessDenied` when attempting to issue the call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*`. If I remove `WithAppOnly()`, the call succeeds [if Delegated rights for Sites.Read.All is assigned]. The Azure AD registered app has admin approved Application-scoped `Sites.Read.All` assigned to it.

```cs
            var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
            {
                new QueryOption("search","*")
            };

            var sites = await graphServiceClient.Sites.Request(queryOptions)
                .WithAppOnly()
                .WithScopes("Sites.Read.All")
                .GetAsync();
```

```
ServiceException: Code: accessDenied
Message: Access denied
Inner error:
AdditionalData:
date: 2021-03-20T21:45:27
request-id: 16933bd6-5e7f-4820-9563-fec75575c9b2
client-request-id: 16933bd6-5e7f-4820-9563-fec75575c9b2
ClientRequestId: 16933bd6-5e7f-4820-9563-fec75575c9b2
```

Comment: Pick up your accessToken, put it in https://jwt.ms and see if you have the Sites.Read.All in `roles` claim.

Comment: Yea, it certainly isn't picking up any Sites.* permission levels. But the AAD app has the rights and the app should be requesting those same rights. I do see Group.ReadWrite.All, which is another API it was granted access to and retrieving Groups works, yet I'm not requesting the permissions differently between Sites and Groups.

Comment: FWIW I'm following the documentation at https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/1.2.0#you-can-now-specify-scopes-and-app-permissions-for-graphserviceclient. So while for some odd reason I have Groups.ReadWrite.All, Sites.Read.All, ReadWrite, etc. are not in the token.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **Sites.Read.All** of **applicaiton** permission in the Azure portal.
[image]

**Note:** Click the [image], because this permission is admin consent required.

Try to test with [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).

```
// Get access token
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id={client_id}
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&client_secret={client_secret}
&grant_type=client_credentials

// Call MS Graph API
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search={query}
```

Comment: This isn't the problem as the application already has that (among other) rights. For some reason it is only picking up `Group.ReadWrite.All` and `User.Read`.

Comment: @TrevorSeward Have you tried to delete the `.WithScopes("Sites.Read.All")` in your code? When using app permissions, the scope needs to be `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`.

Comment: Tried it, unfortunately no change to the Roles. It is still only picking up those two roles. I'd understand if it wasn't picking up any roles, but to selectively pick up just two is really strange.